# converting mongoDB query to spring Data query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have the following working query:

```
db.shops.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:{
        from: "likedShops",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "shop",
        as: "shops"
    }
},
{ 
    $unwind: { path: "$shops", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
},
{
    $match: { 'shops.user': ObjectId("5c04b943ff491824b806686a") }
}
])
```

I'm trying the following in my spring boot project but the result size is 0, should be 2:

```
public void shopList() {
        LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
                .from("likedShops")
                .localField("_id")
                .foreignField("shop")
                .as("shops");
        UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("shops", true);

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwindOperation, Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("shops.user").is(new ObjectId("5c04b943ff491824b806686a"))), lookupOperation);
        List<Shop> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "shops", Shop.class).getMappedResults();
        LOGGER.info("Obj Size " + results.size());
    }
```

Comment: I would start by enabling logging `logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG` then view the actual MongoDB query being executed by Spring and compare it with your Mongo query you are trying to convert.

Comment: looks fine: `[ { "$unwind" : { "path" : "$shops" , "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true}} , { "$match" : { "shops.user" : { "$oid" : "5c04b943ff491824b806686a"}}} , { "$lookup" : { "from" : "likedShops" , "localField" : "_id" , "foreignField" : "shop" , "as" : "shops"}}] in collection shops`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the newAggregation method's parameters matters, should be:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation
                .newAggregation(lookupOperation, unwindOperation, Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("shops.user")
                        .is(new ObjectId(userId))));
```